# Does GetRange() fail if it doesn't meet the count?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Looked through the documentation in the .NET reference but it didn't say.

```
List<TransactionInfo> currentIdsForValuation = allIds.GetRange(counter, 7000);
```

Will this fail if the list has less than 7000 items remaining? Or will it just take all the remaining elements? I want the latter.

Comment: It does say and its easy to test anyway.

Comment: try it, should be easy to get an example with less than 7000 elements.

Comment: A tip - instead of a downvote - is to use a tool such as LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) to try out small bits of code yourself, if you're unsure of things like this. Don't let the name fool you, it's a rather nicely featured code scratch pad. =) (No, I'm not affiliated, just a satisfied user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx,

> `ArgumentException`, index and count do not denote a valid range of elements in the `List<T>`.

A tip: Use a tool such as [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) to try out small bits of code yourself, if you're unsure of things like this. Don't let the name fool you, it's a rather nicely featured code scratch pad.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) says:

> ArgumentException - index and count do not denote a valid range of elements in the List.

So, if the count is out of the range, as you describe, I would expect an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: How would I change it to get what's left if I try-catch that exception?

Comment: @slandau - Since `List` provides a `Count` property, you should use that to figure out if you are going to go over.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) suggests to me that you will get an `ArgumentException`

You could just try it.